# Writing a very large sparse matrix to file in R

Tags: r, bigdata, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix with the dimensions of ~400K x ~8k.

I would like to save this as either a tab delimited or csv file, as I need it as an input to another program.

I used the write.matrix function from the MASS package as suggested from this post:
[How to save an adjacency matrix as a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816180/how-to-save-an-adjacency-matrix-as-a-csv-file/31816367)

However, I get the following error:

```
library(MASS)
write.matrix(data,"data_sparseMat.txt",sep="\t")  
#Error in asMethod(object) : Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
```

Looking at the help, I then tried giving the blocksize parameter. I tried 1000, 10000, 100000. All gave me the same error

```
write.matrix(data,"data_sparseMat.txt",sep="\t", blocksize=1000)  
Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
```

I would appreciate any insight, what am I overlooking?

R version:

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
```

Example:

```
w <- data.table( "id" = 1:300000 , "code" = paste(letters,1:9000,sep=""), "measure"=1:3000)
w$id <- factor(w$id)
w$code <- factor(w$code)

z<- sparseMatrix(as.integer(w$id),as.integer(w$code),x=w$measure,dimnames=list(levels(w$id),levels(w$code)))
write.matrix(z,"sparseTest.txt",sep="\t")
write.matrix(z,"sparseTest.txt",sep="\t",blocksize=100000)
```

NOTE: when code is just 1000 or 3000 instead of 9000, it appears that it is written to file albeit slowly.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Your file will be huge. Wouldn't it better if you save it as a sparse matrix on the file?

Comment: The first line of `MASS::write.matrix` is `x <- as.matrix(x)` so you are likely hitting memory constraints. If you comment this line out, you can probably write the matrix out with the zeros as `.`. Is that doable / can you fiz that in the prgram you read in to? Or can the other program read `mtx` files -- see `Matrix::writeMM`

Comment: 400,000 x 8,000 = 3,200,000,000 bytes just to handle the commas and the carriage returns. Then add in your data. You will need more than that much memory available. Also, you will need a modern file system in order to be able to handle the file size. If you are using HFS you will need to be using version 7.5.2 or newer (this may be a problem if your computer was upgraded from a previous version of MacOS and wasn't originally High Sierra). If you are saving this file to a FAT32 partition you will also have a problem where the file is too large to save in a single file.

Comment: @user20650: Thanks. The other program needs a tab or csv file and needs 0's. However, I also tried to write the sparsematrix with just '.', I get the same error.

Answer (score 4):

This is a workaround using Python. I managed to export a matrix that was too big in R.

Export data in R as sparse matrix:

```
library(Matrix)
write(colnames(sparsematrix), file = "colnames.txt")
write(rownames(sparsematrix), file = "rownames.txt")
writeMM(sparsematrix, file = "sparsematrix.txt")
```

Read then convert in Python:

```
from scipy import sparse, io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sparsematrix = io.mmread('sparsematrix.txt')

m_dense = sparsematrix.toarray()

var_names = np.genfromtxt('rownames.txt', dtype=str)
col_names = np.genfromtxt('colnames.txt', dtype=str)

# Export to txt:
df = pd.DataFrame(m_dense, columns=col_names, index=var_names)
df.to_csv('export_sparsematrix.txt', sep='\t', header=True, index=True, index_label='Somelabel')
```

You can leave out the row and column name part and export the values only with `np.savetxt('m_dense.txt', m_dense, delimiter='\t')`.

Comment: writeMM is very slow. Did someone find a faster way to transfer a big sparse matrix from R to Python?